# 正規分布：一定の範囲内にある確率を求めるには？

Tags: python

以下の問題を解きたいと考えています。

テストの平均が67点、分散が28。40人を無作為に抽出、平均が65点から69点の範囲にある確率を求めたい。

scipyのnormで計算すると思うのですが、p1 と p2 をどう組み合わせるかわかりません。

```
from scipy.stats import norm

p1 = norm.cdf(x = 65, loc = 67, scale = ((28/40)**0.5))
p2 = norm.cdf(x = 69, loc = 67, scale = ((28/40)**0.5))
```

それとも全く別のコードになるのか、すいませんが教えていただけますでしょうか。

Comment: プログラムではなくて数学で解を求めることはできますか？

Comment: 度数分布表を使わないやり方があればと思いました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自分の数学もいまいちが、中心極限定理みればでそちらの計算は賛同！
なので p2-p1 = 0.9831... は「平均が65点から69点の範囲にある確率」かなと思う。

[中心極限定理 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E5%BF%83%E6%A5%B5%E9%99%90%E5%AE%9A%E7%90%86)

Comment: そうか！！正規分布なんですよね。ありがとうございます。